# Getting address coordinates through Google geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding

i am trying to get the coordinates of an address via Google geocoding, and it works almost correctly using this:

```
function getAddressCoordinates() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = $('#cAddress').get(0).value;
    var lat = 0;
    var long = 0;

    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                alert("The coordinates of the entered address are: \nLatitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lat()+"\nLongitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                long = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            }
            else {
                alert("Geocoding failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    } 
    alert ("Lat: "+lat+", \nLng: "+long);
}
```

Problem: the 'lat' and 'long' variables are not given the correct values, they remain 0, despite the fact that the alert shows the correct coordinates. Another observation: the last alert pops up first, then the one from the 'if'. Sorry for noob question and thank you in advance!

Comment: can you put another similar alert inside the `if`, and post the value it shows. Geocoding service is asynchronous service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert("The coordinates of the....)` will triggered only after completing the geocode  callback function. But the `alert ("Lat: "+lat+", \nLng: "+long);` will fire immediately after the `if (geocoder) { }` condition without waiting for anything. That is why you are getting the 0 value for lat and long.

Here assigning the values in global variable is not a good idea. What yo can do is write the further code inside the callback function itself like

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

   alert("The coordinates of the entered address are: \nLatitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lat()+"\nLongitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
   lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
   long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

   furtherProcessing(lat,long);
}
```

// define `furtherProcessing` function outside the call back

```
function furtherProcessing(lat,long) {
 // do what ever with lat n long
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
*read comments*

```
function getAddressCoordinates() {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = $('#cAddress').get(0).value;
var lat = 0;
var long = 0;

if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            alert("The coordinates of the entered address are: \nLatitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lat()+"\nLongitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            // this section gets executed only after geocoding service call is complete
            // so return/alert your lat long values from here
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocoding failed: " + status);
        }
    });
} 
// as geocoding service is asynchronous, it executes immediately with 0 values
alert ("Lat: "+lat+", \nLng: "+long);
```

}